# VC++ compiler doesnt see any of my namespacec or classes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, compilation, namespaces

I'm working on a project in c++ and I stuck with no idea what is wrong. I've writen 4 classes and everything looked fine during work (under visual studio 2010). VS 'saw' all the definition, i could use auto-fill and sudgestions, but when I tried to compile the project it sudennly went blind. It's like I didnt include headers or something (which I did). The strange thing is there is no problem with working with those classes on VS (i can ctrl+space for hint, list of attributes and methods and all that stuff) but when i try to compile it says "ClassName" is not a type.
Quick sample of problem below:

ProButton.cpp:

```
#include "ProButton.h"

using namespace pGUI;

ProButton::ProButton( ... )
    : ProControl( ... )
{
    ...
}
```

ProButton.h:

```
#ifndef __PRO_BUTTON__
#define __PRO_BUTTON__

#include <string>
#include "ProControl.h"

namespace pGUI
{

class ProButton :
    public pGUI::ProControl
{
public:
    //attributes
    ...

public:
    //methods
    ...

};

}


#endif
```

but compiler says:
Error   291 error C2653: 'ProButton' : is not a class or namespace name
for this line in ProButton.cpp: ProButton::ProButton( ... )

It also says:
Error   23  error C2039: 'ProControl' : is not a member of 'pGUI'
Error   24  error C2504: 'ProControl' : base class undefined

and all similar errors for whole project. I have no idea what is wrong. Looks like my VS broke :D

Of course those (...) means there is code there, just not that important for now. I can upload all solution somewhere fi it will help.

**edit//**

About namespaces, all header files (classes declaration) are defined in namespace with:

```
namespace pGUI{
   class ProClass
   {
   };
}
```

all definitions for these classes (in ProClass.cpp) are using:

```
using namespace pGUI;
```

at the beginning.

I think the problem is with order of including files.
Im not sure how this is supposed to be done. So far i have 4 classes that:

**class ProGUI:**

- has a pointer to ProContainer
- *includes: ProContainer and ProControl*

**class ProContainer:**

- has pointers to: ProGUI and ProControl

**class ProControl:**

- has a pointer to ProContainer
- *includes ProButton*
- is a base class for ProButton

**class ProButton:**

- is a sub-class of ProControl

Those classes also uses irrlicht library and I'm not sure where to include it.
I had it included in my main file just before `#include "ProGUI.h"`. This is also the only include in main. ProGUI.h .

**//EDIT 2 -> solved**

It was a problem with includes. I needed to rethink my inclusion order and add some forward declarations. Anyway that all seemed strange and took me a lot of time to figure i out. Thx for help. :)

Comment: *Is* `ProControl` in the `pGUI` namespace? This code doesn't confirm that is true. Any chance you can include `ProControl.h` as well?

Comment: It's doubtful that VS is broken here. Is that the first error you're getting? Try to give us a minimal but complete (no "..."s) sample that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The answer is in your edit:  ProControl includes ProButton.  Why would it do that?  ProButton should include ProControl.  (As it does in your above code.)

Comment: If you just need to declare a pointer or reference in a class, you can get away with a forward declaration at the top of the header file where the pointer/reference will be declared. You only need to include a header file in another when you need access to the whole type declared in the included header file, such as when deriving from another class, or including a non-pointer member in a class.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are using following statement:

`using namespace pGUI;`

Just before the class declaration:

```
class ProControl
{

};
```

Instead of using following approach:

```
namespace pGUI
{
    class ProControl
    {

    };
}
```

The `using namespace`, as it says *uses* a namespace. You need to explicitly put something a namespace using `namespace` keyword followed by braces!

Comment: I am using: namespace pGUI{    } in all header files and using namespace pGUI; in .cpp files. Im not sure if this is correct. I think the biggest problem is with including files (its order). I edited question to add some more info.

Comment: The first compiler error says it all (C2653). Do *not* use `using namespace` try placing `namespace pGUI {` instead.

Comment: changing `using namespace pGUI;` for `namespace pGUI{` didnt help.

Comment: Can't help this way. There is something you are missing. Try to find it!

Answer (score 1):

`using namespace pGUI` informs the compiler that it should look in the pGUI namespace to resolve existing names.

To declare or implement something in a namespace you need to be more specific.  with either:

```
namespace pGUI
{
    ProButton::ProButton( ... ) : ProControl( ... )
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

or:

```
pGUI::ProButton::ProButton( ... ) : ProControl( ... )
{
    ....
}
```

Personally, I consider any use of `using namespace` to be a lazy programmer hack that completely defeats the point of namespaces.  But I digress.  :)

Comment: Your aswer is the same as a previous one that was deleted, and it's not true, I've always used **using** declarations to implement methods and it works fine.

Comment: ok, fair enough.  I didn't know that.  (Just tried it out now.)  I still can't say I advocate using `using` though.  It is a hack that should never have been included in the language.